# elsarticle: two title pages, one with only title and author information, and another with only title and abstract

Tags: titles, elsarticle, abstract, front-matter

I'm using the elsarticle class and I would like to have the following:

First page: Only title and author information (affiliation, address etc)

Second page: Only title, abstract, and keywords, *without* author information.

The text should start on the third page.

I've found ways to put the abstract in the second page by patching `\pprintMaketitle` to remove the horizontal lines above and below the abstract on the first page, and add the abstract with the horizontal lines on the second page. While this works to send the abstract to the second page, I also need the title on the second page. In the MWE below, I tried to reuse the `frontmatter` environment adding the abstract only on the second time. However, it seems the author information is carried over to the second page, even if I use `\author[]{}` the second time I call `frontmatter`.

Is there a way to achieve what I want with elsarticle?

Thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear, times]{elsarticle}

\linespread{1.5}
\makeatother

\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
   \let\@oddhead\@empty
   \let\@evenhead\@empty
   \let\@oddfoot\@empty
   \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{\textbf{Title goes here}}

\author[a1]{John Doe\corref{cor1}}
\cortext[cor1]{John Doe notes}
\ead{john@doe.com}
\address[a1]{John Doe's affiliation}

\end{frontmatter}

\newpage

\begin{frontmatter}

\author[]{}

\begin{abstract}
Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper. Summary of what John Doe did in this paper.  
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
keyword 1 \sep keyword 1\\
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\newpage
\end{document}
```